# Why hibernate creates connections for nothing?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, database-performance

I applied hibernate statistics log. And for test purpose I get list of entities from the DB and among the normal log - where it shows the statements,execution times..etc - I discovered session metrics with 0 values like this:

```
Session Metrics {
    74800 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent preparing 0 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections);
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
}
```

What is this means? Hibernate opens the connection for no purpose and never release it?

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate create a pool of connections and use connection from pool when its necessary.
Its much cheaper than opening new connection every time. Read about "connection pooling mechanism".